# How to commit git message locally using an editor?

Tags: git, sublimetext, commit

I'm trying to commit my changes locally i.e. using `git commit` command.
It launches the Sublime editor successfully, where one can enter the desired message for the commits.

**Failed Attempts to add Personal Messages and Commit via Sublime editor**

My git terminal remains stuck and receives no input from the Sublime editor, even after I enter
the desired message, save it and close the editor!

I can successfully commit using this command: `git commit -m "my_desired_message"`

Is there a way to use SublimeText to enter my commit message?

Comment: Type this command in a repo `git config core.editor`. What is the output?

Comment: @DivyanshuKushwaha 'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe' -n -w
This is the output, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen in some discussions that there are problems with commits on Sublime if it's already open.

Do you already have Sublime open when you enter git commit?

Try this to see if it works.

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"
```

Associating text editors with Git
-n will open a new instance of Sublime.
-w will make the git wait for you to close Sublime before proceeding.

Let me know if either of those two work.